# Intercept a bluetooth communication between two devices

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I would like to ideally be able to watch two Bluetooth devices communicate and see what exactly is sent between them.

Now I know it isn't possible to MITM Bluetooth directly, but in theory I don't need to since I could pair both devices with a Linux PC in theory, and with any luck there is hopefully a way for the Linux PC to relay the comms between the two.

I'm trying to reverse engineer a specific command between a device and a iOS app and this seems to be the most logical approach. My Googling isn't giving me any pointers on where to look however. I do know Wireshark will sniff data PC -> device, but I need iOS -> PC -> Device.

Comment: But the comms is between IOS <-> device. The PC does not come into play at all. Pairing with the PC does not make the IOS<->device comms suddenly go through the PC. So what you want, IOS->PC->Device is exactly MITM. Unless I'm misunderstanding your set up. I don't know much about IOS (Android user here) but aren't there Wireshark equivalent apps for IOS (there are for Andoid)?

Comment: I'm thinking like NAT with networks. To the iOS app, the PC acts as the device, to the device the PC acts as the iOS app. In reality the PC is just passing the messages between the two just like a router.
It is MITM, but it isn't the PC trying to sniff the data over the air when the iOS app and the device are communicating directly to each other.

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth